# Fetch last row in table with no unique identifier and without using ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have Data like

```
column1   column2  column3 
Data101    Data2   Data3
Data100    Data20  Data355
Data10     Data2   Data3lh
```

Unstructured data in table, with no unique column and no indexes

I want last row

**Output:**

```
Data10     Data2   Data3lh
```

Comment: There isn't any guaranteed way without using `ORDER BY` to find the last ;).

Comment: actually table is created,without pk column, and other column data are not structured to do order by.
We can't edit table, as client not allowed to do it

Comment: if wonder how you even know what's the last row? I could be different everytime you select from the table...

Answer (score 8):

Without any sorting criteria there's NO WAY to achieve this. There's no guarantee for any order if you do a simple

`SELECT * FROM xy`.

You could get your result in any sort order. Very dangerous: With small sets this might work *accidentally* in development and pass all your tests but breaks in production.

If you want to get the rows in the order of their insert you should add an `IDENTITY` column.

If you want to enforce a pseudo-order you could try with `ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY somecolumn)` AS `PseudoInx`.