# How can I return the top N most recently inserted records from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table `Records` with a column `Timestamp` which records external data, however it has come to light that some data sources are providing wrong timestamp data due to clock issues. This means that records inserted today might have a timestamp from 1999 for instance, and since we don't have a column `insert_time` they are hard to spot.

So I want to find the most recently added database rows. I have come across `ROW_NUMBER()` but that seems to assign a value to the ordering used in the query.

Say I want to find the last 100 rows inserted into `Records`, how can I do this? Searching has shown me references to special/undocumented functionality but I cannot see a straightforward answer to this question - does one exist?

We are using a pretty modern version of SQLServer, I think 2019.

Comment: Short of digging in to the transaction log, you can't. SQL Server doesn't maintain a "most recently inserted" index for rows unless you define one yourself.

Comment: Without a column that tells you when a row was inserted, that's going to be pretty difficult, because SQL Server doesn't track it for you. There are several ways to turn this on from this point forward (add a column with a default value, triggers, CDC/CT, temporal, etc.) but I think you should focus on having the data sources not send you unreliable garbage.

Comment: If you have an identity column, you could order by that column in descending order.

Comment: So there's no hidden row-id type field, MSSQL doesn't itself know what order rows were added? @AaronBertrand this is historic data, fixing the problem going forward doesn't really help investigating existing rows

Comment: @Mr.Boy - No, SQL Server doesn't know or have any reason to care the order they were added

Comment: If the answer is "no" or "it can't be done" then someone please consider providing that - it is a perfectly proper answer :)

Comment: There isn't. It's been asked a bunch of times, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31266137/61305) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40020319/61305).

Comment: There's no special mystic magic undocumented functionality for this either. If someone presented something as this, I guarantee you it will break on something as simple as an `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD`, page split, or anything else that could change the physical order of rows. The closest thing there is to a "hidden row-id type field" is the uniquifier that the engine adds to a clustered index on a non-unique column. This does not indicate insert order, though, and crucially, the uniquifier will not even be assigned unless it actually has to be to make rows unique.